# How to find commits of git submodules for specific commit of root repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The question is: How to find commits of each submodule of git repo recorded in some specific commit (without checking this commit out).

I know, that for the working copy I can use

```
git ls-files --stage
```

which would give me (among other things) commits recorded for each submodule.

The problem is that I want to see this information for the commit in the root repo, which is not checked out.

---

For those, who are interested, the question comes from the need to merge branches in the repo with lots of submodules. Funny enough, this question is not extensively covered in the internet (or I cannot use google).

Let's say, I have two branches in the root repo: `branch_a` and `branch_b`. And I want to merge *some* *commit* from `branch_b` into `branch_a`. To be specific, let's say, that I want to merge the commit with hash `bbb123`.

- For this I need to find out, which commits were recorded in the `branch_b` of the root repo in commit `bbb123` for each submodule. [Exactly for this I need the answer to my question].
- Now I should check, if these commits of submodules differ from the commits of corresponding submodule recorded in `branch_a`, where I want to merge.
- If commits are the same, then I should do nothing, but if the commits are different, then I should merge corresponding commit of submodule (recorded in `branch_b`) into the same submodule it it's sate in `branch_a`.
- After it is done for all submodules, I can merge the root repos. Git will propose me then to use newly created merge-comits of submodules as resolution of conflicts. [If fact I could first start merge in root repos, then submodules with different comments would be reported as conflicts, which I would need to resolve by merging submodules.]

Probably I over-complicate. If someone knows simpler way of doing it, I'd appreciate it also...

Comment: `git ls-tree -r -t <commit> | grep -e '^160000 commit'`

Comment: @ElpieKay: Thanks. You should've post it as normal reply, so that I can accept it as a solution. I even looked at this command myself, but first did not understand, what it does... git terminology sometimes can be confusing for those, who are not used to it.